# Why won't Karate let me read in variables from another feature file?

Tags: karate

If I have feature file A I should be able to call feature file B to use as a store of file contants.

So, like:

`def MyExpectedResult = read call(MyExpectedResultContants.feature)`

```
Given <endpoint>
When get
Then status 200
And match response contains MyExpectedResult
```

This is not supported after spending a lot of time trying to get that to work. A constants file is a basic thing it would be nice if Karate supported.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say in `constants.feature` you have :

```
def variable1 = "string1"
def variable2 = { json: "value" }
```

If you call

```
def constants = call read(constants.feature)
```

Then you can do

```
* match constants.variable1 == "string1"
* match constants.variable2.json == "value"
```

If that's not what you want, then you should edit your post.

Comment: thanks :) note that just `* call read(constants.feature)` will result in the variables being created directly as "globals" without a prefix. also see this part of the docs for extra info: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multiple-functions-in-one-file